# How to enable API access for 'Facebook At Work' for Graph API Explorer?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebookatwork

I am looking to retrieve group feeds of a group created in **'Facebook At Work'**(i.e. the URL will be like http://companyname.facebook.com) using **Graph API Explorer** but its disabled by default for **'Facebook At Work'**
[See Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-at-work/graph-api/overview#enableapiaccess). Now I tried to follow its steps to enable the same and searched each & every link but I couldn't find **Manage Work Community** option as mentioned in documentation. This is what I am getting in my dropdown option.
[image]
So where can I find that link? How to enable **API access** for **Facebook At Work**.

Comment: Hi Varun hope you may implemented posting message on facebook @ work. we want to implement similar kind of module in our organization. If you have any API code to access the following requirement, pls share thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39391756/how-to-post-message-on-facebook-at-work-group-using-graph-api

Comment: @watraplion:The code for FB@Work is not much different. The only difference comes in admin settings or in the way you do it depending on your requirement. I can help you with the same.

Comment: '@Varun thank you so much for the response. I have tried to access the user profile by creating WebRequest to https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/{your ID}. But this throws bad web request error.. I have admin rights on my org facebook account. Pls help me to get it work. Where should i use the Application token key & community ID in the context.

Comment: @watraplion: You must be missing something or doing something in a wrong way like missing some parameters permissions or format of the data, etc. Sorry for late response.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response Varun.. We have implemented this :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got answer to my question thus I will be describing my problem & its solution in detail so it will not only help people to understand problems I had but it will also help those who are stuck in the same situation.So here it goes.
**Motive**: We need to **access Group post data** created in **Facebook At Work(FAW)** account using Graph API.
**Problem**: 
1) Problem revolves around **two** things, **Community** & **Access Token** and I was unable to access either of them in order to **enable** the **Disabled Graph API**.
 
2) There are two steps to get access token. One via **Admin Access Token** in which I was unable emulate the steps mentioned as it was **not correctly documented** in FB Dev.
3) What is a **Community**? How to create it in FAW? How to access it is not properly mentioned in the documentation.
4) Second method is **Member access Tokens** in this we get per person data but of members belonging to a Community & not group. Which brings us to same question mentioned above.

**Solution in Short**: You need **admin rights** to do the steps mentioned in the doc.

**Solution in Detail:** ***Community & Access Tokens*** are only available to the **admin** or **superadmin** or/and the **owner** of the FAW a/c & not to any other users below it. As the user a/c given to us was not superadmin thus we didn't got option to access the same.
        ***If you don't have that access then you either need to tell the admin to promote you to that level or someone from the admin to hand over you those details to you directly***.

Answer (score 1):

you can follow the documentation : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-at-work/graph-api/overview

- From the drop-down menu in Facebook at Work, click Manage Work
  Community
- Click the Settings tab
- Under Basic Settings, **enable Sync membership through an external
  application**. via the check-box
- Retrieve your access token

You can access to your groups through the graph API with your access token

you need the Community ID

`https://graph.facebook.com/{community-id}/groups?access_token={your_admin_access_token}&limit=500`

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to post the answer but it doesn't answer my question. My question was where can I find **Manage Work Community** option as I have shown in my question itself that in my dropdown **Manage Work Community** is not visible. But I have finally got the answer to my question which I am posting right now.

Comment: Great good luck :)